# Save a file with saveas dialog?

Tags: c#

Can I save a file without the save as dialog?

Comment: Actually, the "Save-as" dialog has little to do with the act of *saving* (creating / writing / over-writing / appending) a file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you must have a filename. File dialog is only to determinate good filename where write the file.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you know the path you want to save it to.
You can use the methods of [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), like [WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx), [WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx), or [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely vague, but taking a wild stab at it:

Yes, just use the classes in the [`System.IO` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx). There's an example in the [`FileStream` class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), for instance; quoting it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        // Delete the file if it exists.
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }

        //Create the file.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            AddText(fs, "This is some text");
            AddText(fs, "This is some more text,");
            AddText(fs, "\r\nand this is on a new line");
            AddText(fs, "\r\n\r\nThe following is a subset of characters:\r\n");

            for (int i=1;i < 120;i++)
            {
                AddText(fs, Convert.ToChar(i).ToString());

            }
        }

        //Open the stream and read it back.
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
            while (fs.Read(b,0,b.Length) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddText(FileStream fs, string value)
    {
        byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(value);
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
}
```

@All: Again, this is a quote from the documentation, not original code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You can use StreamWriter class:

```
FileInfo t = new FileInfo("f.txt");
StreamWriter Tex =t.CreateText();
Tex.WriteLine("Hello");
Tex.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class.